# pyspark 2.3.3 connectivity issue with oracle database via jupyter notebook

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB 11R2 from Pyspark, IDE I am using is Jupyter Notebook. But unable to connect however I am able to connect to Oracle DB via Spark Shell but hard luck with Jupyter Notebook on my laptop.
I am using below piece of code to connect to Oracle:

empdf=spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl").option("dbtable","EMP").option("user","scott").option("password","scott").option("driver","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").load()
Referred below link but didn't worked:
[Trying to connect to Oracle from Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768697/trying-to-connect-to-oracle-from-spark)

Kindly help.

Comment: can you add the error you are receiving ?

Comment: Error I am facing is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver